# $f$ analytic such that $f (z)$ has only essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic such that $1/f(z)$ has only essential singularity. Then which of the following hold?

a) $f$ must be a polynomial.

b) $f$ cannot be a polynomial.

c) $f (1/z)$ must have a pole.

d) $f (1/z)$ must have an essential singularity.

$f(z)=e^{-1/z}$ has essesntial singularity at $z=0$ so $c,d,a$ are out and so $b$ is true. Am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is intentional, but your username is spelled wrong. It's 'thief,' not 'theif.'

Answer (score 2):

You are right. To show $b$, note that the inverse of a polynomial is meromorphic.

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: @BicycleTheif I have edited my answer.